# Tensorflow example for Android

Tags: android, python-2.7, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Tensorflow has provided this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) as an example for using tensorflow on Android apps.

I have successfully built the app and launched it on my device. I read the code as well.

But I can't figure out where to go from here! I have a tensorflow code that calculates accuracy given the training data.

How do I use that model in my own android app. The tensorflow description doesn't go beyond build instructions.

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to save your model to a .pb(protobuf) file. 
In your application you will need to load this .pb file. You can achieve this with `tf/python/tools freeze_graph.freeze_graph()`

You also going to need libtensorflow_inference.so which contains all the c++ implementation.

Last you will need the libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar.

With these you can then write:

```
inferenceInterface.initializeTensorFlow(getAssets(), MODEL_FILE);

inferenceInterface.fillNodeFloat(INPUT_NODE, INPUT_SIZE, inputFloats);

inferenceInterface.runInference(new String[] {OUTPUT_NODE});

inferenceInterface.readNodeFloat(OUTPUT_NODE, resu);
```

There is a great tutorial over here: https://omid.al/posts/2017-02-20-Tutorial-Build-Your-First-Tensorflow-Android-App.html

GitHub repo for the app: https://github.com/omimo/TFDroid

For me this helped a lot at understanding the basics of tf on Android.

Answer (score 0):

There are some good tutorials out there which should walk you through the steps.

Assuming we are talking about an image classification problem, you should just need to:

- Process your TensorFlow model using the `strip_unused` tool (to make it compatible with the Android demo app).
- Copy your stripped TensorFlow `.pb` model and your `.txt` of your new labels into the Android `assets` folder.
- Build the Android demo app again.

For more information, check out [this blog post](https://medium.com/@daj/creating-an-image-classifier-on-android-using-tensorflow-part-3-215d61cb5fcd#.a7c4lc5xx) where I wrote up how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The completed detailed way to build TensorFlow for Android

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Note: --recurse-submodules is important to pull submodules.

Install Bazel from here. Bazel is the primary build system for TensorFlow.
Now, edit the WORKSPACE, we can find the WORKSPACE file in the root directory of the TensorFlow that we have cloned earlier.

```
# Uncomment and update the paths in these entries to build the Android demo.
#android_sdk_repository(
#    name = "androidsdk",
#    api_level = 23,
#    build_tools_version = "25.0.1",
#    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
#    path = "<PATH_TO_SDK>",
#)
#
#android_ndk_repository(
#    name="androidndk",
#    path="<PATH_TO_NDK>",
#    api_level=14)
```

Like below with our sdk and ndk path:

```
android_sdk_repository(
    name = "androidsdk",
    api_level = 23,
    build_tools_version = "25.0.1",
    # Replace with path to Android SDK on your system
    path = "/Users/amitshekhar/Library/Android/sdk/",
)
android_ndk_repository(
    name="androidndk",
    path="/Users/amitshekhar/Downloads/android-ndk-r13/",
    api_level=14)
```

Then build the .so file.

```
bazel build -c opt //tensorflow/contrib/android:libtensorflow_inference.so \
   --crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool \
   --host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain \
   --cpu=armeabi-v7a
```

Replacing armeabi-v7a with our desired target architecture.
The library will be located at:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/android/libtensorflow_inference.so
```

To build the Java counterpart:

```
bazel build //tensorflow/contrib/android:android_tensorflow_inference_java
```

We can find the JAR file at:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/android/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar
```

Now we have both jar and .so file. I have already built both .so file and jar, you can directly use from the [project](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/AndroidTensorFlowMachineLearningExample).

Put libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar in libs folder and right click and add as library.

```
compile files('libs/libandroid_tensorflow_inference_java.jar')
```

Create jniLibs folder in main directory and put libtensorflow_inference.so in jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/ folder.

Now, we will be able to call TensorFlow Java API.

The TensorFlow Java API has exposed all the required methods through a class TensorFlowInferenceInterface.

Now, we have to call the TensorFlow Java API with the model path and load it.

I have written a complete blog [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-tensorflow-machine-learning-example-ff0e9b2654cc).